# how to get the contents inside a div along with all html tags along with values present in text box etc tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to get the contents inside a div along with all html tags along with values present in text box etc tags .
The jQuery function `$('#divid').html()` is working in IE but the firefox i am getting the html but the values which are in text area and text box are not setting.

Thanks,
Shriniket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would continue to do as you are doing to get the html, and then use the jquery form plugin to get the values of the fields.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

```
var value = $('#divid').fieldValue();
```

value will be an array of values, you may also like fieldSerialize() which return the name value pairs url encoded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the content correctly with html, because it only gives you `innerHTML` of the div element.

You can have a reference to DOM element of that div.

```
$("#divid").get(0);
```

with this reference you can move that element to any place in DOM trees.